# Complexified tangent space in Complex geometry

Tags: complex-geometry, curvature, kahler-manifolds, tangent-spaces

Let $(M,J)$ be a complex manifold and let $z^i=x^i+iy^i,\ i=1,\ldots,{\rm dim_\mathbb C \ M}$ be its coordinates on a local patch.
Here J is the complex structure, which, for all $p\in M$, is a map $J:\ T_pM\longrightarrow T_pM$ satisfying $J_p=-id_{T_pM}.$ 
In particular it can be extended to the complexified tangent space $T_pM^{\mathbb C}=T_pM\otimes \mathbb C$.

A complex manifold always admits a hermitian metric, satisfying $g(JX,JY)=g(X,Y), \ \forall X,Y\in T_pM$. Again this tensor can be extended to the complexified tangent space.

Once this metric is considered, we induce a connection and one can compute the torsion $T$ or the Riemann curvature tensor $R$, which again can be extended to $T_pM^{\mathbb C}$.

Why do we consider the extension of all these tensors to $T_pM^{\mathbb C}$?
Why should we be interested in computing, for example, the Ricci curvature $S\left(\frac{\partial}{\partial z^i},\frac{\partial}{\partial \bar z^{j}} \right)\equiv S_{i\bar j}$ or the Ricci scalar?
Does the extension of these maps to the complexified vector spaces tell something about the manifold $M$?

My questions stems from the fact that the complexified tangent space has double the dimension of the true tangent space, therefore it is not clear to me what we are actually computing when we are dealing with the former.

Comment: To clarify: As soon as we start writing $z^{j} = x^{j} + iy^{j}$ we're all but obliged to complexify the tangent bundle, it's natural to express geometric quantities on $TM$ in terms of the holomorphic tangent bundle $T^{1,0}M$ (and/or the conjugate bundle $T^{0,1}M$), and mathematical curiosity (if nothing else) urges us on. So, by "why?" are you asking "What leads us to complexify?", or "Why don't we just do real geometry with $TM$?", or "Do we obtain anything new (e.g., the Kähler form, the Ricci form)?", or something else...?

Comment: My question can be summed up by the last two questions that you mentioned "Why don't we just do real geometry with ?" and "Do we obtain anything new?"

As far as I understand, the Kähler form, the Ricci form and Riemann tensor, the hermitian metric and so on are all defined without resorting to complexification.

But then when they are expressed in local coordinates, I always see `z` and `\bar z`.

Comment: Thank you; I expect the answer essentially boils down to "convenience". In the simplest case, we might develop complex analysis in the real Cartesian plane without referring to $z = x + iy$, but there are notational and conceptual simplifications, and powerful idioms, coming from holomorphic formalism, starting with the Cauchy-Riemann equations as "constancy in $\bar{z}$".

Comment: Thank you for your answer @AndrewD.Hwang! I understand that it is convenient to compute things using complexified vector fields, but how can I be sure that I would obtain the same result as if I used the usual real vector fields?
For example, suppose I compute the Ricci scalar: what is its geometrical meaning if I use complexified vector fields?

Answer (score 1):

The main reason to complexify the tangent bundle is so that one can construct the $\pm i$ eigenspaces of $J$. The $+i$ eigenspace $T^{1,0}M$ is a holomorphic vector bundle ($\mathbb{C}^{n}$'s glued together by holomorphic matrices $\frac{\partial \phi^k_{i \bar j}}{\partial z_l}$ for holomorphic transition maps $\phi_{i \bar j} $ of the underlying manifold). Then the top exterior power of the dual bundle $T^{1,0}M^*$ is called the canonical bundle.

In the case of a compact Kahler manifold, under some assumptions, the sections of the canonical bundle embed the manifold into the complex projective space as a projective variety (Kodaira embedding). This provides one with all the techniques from algebraic geometry to study the complex manifold.

There are ways of studying complex manifolds without complexification. See these notes https://people.math.osu.edu/derdzinski.1/courses/7721/kg.pdf. But this will not give the strong results obtainable by using algebraic techniques.